# Change IIS port on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have been mostly involved with Java servlets running Tomcat but now have an ASP.NET project to maintain and need to install IIS.  I am concerned about the two web server applications conflicting and so I want to change the port on IIS.  This URL below explains how to change the port for certain websites on IIS but can I change the default port on IIS completely?  I am running Windows 7 so I believe it is IIS 7.5

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149605#/en-us/kb/149605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the port as stated in the link. If no site is binding to port 80 (or whatever port you want free) iis wont be listening to it.

Comment: Thanks.  Okay.  So just change the port when any new site is deployed on that IIS instance to avoid conflicting with Tomcat port(s)?